# Error visualizing with ListDensityPlot3D

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

I have list of data points having elements {x, y, z, F(x, y, z)}, which I want to plot using ListDensityPlot3D. (x, y, z) are the points on surface of sphere in cartesian system and F(x, y, z) is an integer ranging from 0 - 12. Seems easy, but I am repeatedly getting the following error message.

> Visualization`VectorFields`ListScalarProcessData3D::vfldata

Clicking the error message does not take to any explanation in Mathematica.

Here are few of the data points.

```
X={{0., 0., 1., 3}, {0.0461835, 0., 0.998933, 1}, {0.0922684, 0., 
  0.995734, 1}, {0.138157, 0., 0.99041, 1}, {0.18375, 0., 0.982973, 
  1}, {0.22895, 0., 0.973438, 6}, {0.273663, 0., 0.961826, 
  6}, {0.317791, 0., 0.948161, 6}, {0.361242, 0., 0.932472, 
  6}, {0.403921, 0., 0.914794, 6}, {0.445738, 0., 0.895163, 
  6}, {0.486605, 0., 0.873622, 6}};
```

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: Please share the code that produces the error message.

Comment: ListDensityPlot3D[X]

Comment: This appears to be because your second co-ordinate in all cases is `0`.

Comment: But it should plot it though ! strange.